# While compiling tests cases getting exception Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not start process: <EOF>

Tags: junit, flapdoodle-embed-mongo

Can you please check below issue.

**[2020-10-08T12:30:57.272Z] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoAppConfiig': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Could not start process: EOF
[2020-10-08T12:30:57.272Z] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not start process: EOF**

Version which we are using

```
1. Java version "1.8.0_112" (64-Bit Server )
2. de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.version:- 2.2.0
3. Spring Boot Version :- 2.2.5.RELEASE
4. Mongo DB version(Embeded used in jenkins):- 4.0.2
5. OS:- Linux Centos 7
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware it's pretty long time since you asked but I believe it may be related with problem with not supported linux distribution.
Something like this:
https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo/issues/353